# Is static variable guaranteed to be initialized when used by static methods in the same translation unit?

Tags: c++

I read that the dynamic initialization of static global variables is guaranteed to happen in the order of definition if they are in the same translation unit. Then I wonder whether it is guaranteed that a static global variable must have been dynamic initialized when it is used by a static method defined after it in the same translation unit.

```
//Foo.h
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int i) {m_i = i;}
    int m_i;
};

//X.h
class X
{
    static void doSth();
    static Foo foo;
};

//X.cpp
Foo X::foo(2);
void X::doSth()
{
    //Is it guaranteed that foo has been properly initialized here?
    std::cout << foo.m_i << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No, global initialization has nothing to do with static methods.

Here's a simple scenario that illustrates why: what if the constructor of `Foo` invoked `doSth()`?

If you need that guarantee, you need to use a function-scope static variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just came up with an easy program to try it and indeed the value of foo.m_i is indeterminate if I simply change the order of object files passed to linker. The simple scenario you pointed out is also great and easy to understand. Thanks.

Comment: @leolong if changing the linking order changes the outcome, they weren't in the same translation unit. An object file is the output of a single translation unit.

Comment: @MarkRansom Because in my test program I called doSth() from the constructor of another static object defined in another cpp file.